# Python - Dynamically created dictionary can't be returned or added to another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dynamic

I've got a function that dynamically creates some number of dictionaries. What I'm trying to do, is to add each of those dictionaries to another dictionary, and then return that dictionary of dictionaries.

The dictionaries are all created just fine. I've stepped through the process and inspected the variables, it all looks good.
[image]

But when I try to add them to another dictionary (as a value), all that gets added is None.
[image]

I think this might have something to do with global and local variables, but I'm not sure.

This is the code that creates the dictionaries inside the function

```
def build_DoD(block, page, PROJECT, master_string, logging):     
            # other code up here 

            exec("{} = {{}}".format(base))
            exec("{0}['section'] = '{1}'".format(base, section))
            exec("{}['question_number'] = '{}'".format(base, question_number))
            exec("{}['sub_question_label'] = '{}'".format(base, sub_question_label))
            exec("{}['sub_question_text'] = '{}'".format(base, sub_question_text))
            exec("{}['display_function'] = '{}'".format(base, display_function))
            exec("{}['has_other'] = '{}'".format(base, has_other))
            exec("{}['has_explain'] = '{}'".format(base, has_explain))
            exec("{}['has_text_year'] = '{}'".format(base, has_text_year))
            exec("{}['randomize_response'] = '{}'".format(base, randomize_response))
            exec("{}['response_table'] = '{}'".format(base, resp_table))

             # here is where I try to add the dynamically created dict to a larger dict.
           dict_of_dicts[str(base)] = exec("{}".format(base))
```

Comment: This is such a bad design (with the `exec`s and everything) that maybe it'd be more productive to change your approach rather than fixing this problem

Comment: super helpful, thanks!

Comment: My point is: it looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe it is better for you to describe the solution you are trying to make, rather than trying to fix the specific null thing in the dictionary ;}

Comment: Please fix your code. This is _not_ how dictionaries are created. Beside that, `base` is unknown to us, `section` is unknonw , `question_number` is unknow **etc**. Create a [mcve] that we can copy/paste/execute and see your problem.

Comment: Start researching dicts here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, don't do this. Ever.

Don't use `exec` outside of really special cases. But to answer the question, even if I don't thing you should use it: The problem you are having is that `exec` does not return anything. It *just* *exec*utes the code, it does not *eval*uate it. For that, there is the function `eval`. Replace `exec` in the last line with `eval`.
I however fully agree with @RafaelC. This is the XYProblem

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!  Really appreciate it.

I've only been working with python for a month or two, and I'm completely self-taught.  I can see from everyone's comments that using exec is a bad idea, so I'll re-work things to avoid it. But knowing what my issue was is very helpful, thank you!